# linq sorted string in array by sub string

Tags: c#, arrays, json, linq

sorry I just started learning LINQ, and I would be glad if you would say it is possible to do using Linq sort this array by *ID* or *BonusCount*

```
string[] res;   // {"ID,Name, BonusCount",etc}    
res = new string[] {"1, Mark, 250", "4, Ostin, 150","2, Rick K., 12","11,Robert,1"};
```

I would get:
    by id:

```
{"1, Mark, 250", "2, Rick K., 12", "4, Ostin, 150","11,Robert,1"};
```

by BonusCount:

```
{"11,Robert,1", "2, Rick K., 12", "4, Ostin, 150", "1, Mark, 250"};I
```

Is it possible? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes it is possible and quite easy

```
 var res = new string[] { "1, Mark, 250", "4, Ostin, 150", "2, Rick K., 12", "11,Robert,1" };


 var sortByBonus = res.OrderBy(i => int.Parse(i.Split(',').Last())).ToArray();
 var sortById = res.OrderBy(i => int.Parse(i.Split(',').First())).ToArray();
```

Comment: It is not so easy to think for a Linq newbie though :)